# App Crashes when iAds is integrated. What could be wrong?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have integrated iAds in the app.

Simulator -> Works fine.

iPhone 3G (iOS 4.2.1) - Installed from XCode -> Works fine.

iPhone 4G (iOS 4.0.1) - Tried installing Adhoc -> App crashes after 2 seconds of opening.

I have tried deleting the provisioning profiles and reinstalling them.

What could be wrong?

Please suggest.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the crash logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait constants? Using them will crash on <4.2, use the old ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 instead

Comment: @SVD, Thanks for your reply. It does not crash in 4.2. It crashes in 4.0.1. What could be wrong?

Comment: I said it'll crash on <4.2 (i.e. less than 4.2). 4.0.1 < 4.2, isn't it :P

Comment: @SVD, I directly added the iAds framework and set the size to 320 x 50 through Interface Builder. No coding done as such. What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried simulator v4.0 or 4.1? And what does the crash log say?

Comment: Here's what the device log says: Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x000791d0 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x000791c0 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x000791b2 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x0008d6fa abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x00044a20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                0x000059ec _objc_terminate + 104

Comment: which SDk you use when building? Have you tried a lower one, like 4.1 or 4.0?